# want x-ticks in the order of the values shown in array X

Tags: matplotlib, xticks

I have:

```
X = [1,5,3,4,2]

Y = [10, 14, 11, 9, 10]

plt.plot(X,Y,'o')
```

plots x-axis ticks from `1` to `5`.

I want the x-axis to show values `1,5,3,4,2` in this order.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can if you make the X variable categorical.

Use strings:

```
X = [1,5,3,4,2]
Y = [10, 14, 11, 9, 10]

plt.plot([str(x) for x in X], Y, 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Note: This looks fine when `x` contains all points within an evenly spaced range, but if you have `x = [1, 5, 4, 2]` or `x = [1, 5, 3.5, 4, 2]`, the points will still be displayed with an even spacing despite the fact that the value aren't actually spaced evenly. Though, if you have those `x` vectors and want them plotted in that order, how they should be spaced is undefined.

Comment: @jared I don't believe the points should be other than evenly spaced. For `[1,5,3,4,2]` would it mean that you'd expect a larger gap between 1-5 than 3-4? That doesn't really make sense. If needed OP must clarify. If a custom spacing is wanted then the x values should be replaced by the desired position and strings should be mapped as tick labels.

Comment: Right, that's why I said the spacing is undefined. If we have evenly spaced points that span the whole range, such as in this example, knowing that the sorted points are spaced by 1 unit, if we reordered them, 1 unit spacing makes the most sense. But if the sorted points aren't spaced evenly, I don't know what spacing would make sense in that case.